# How can I see the results of tags being fired from GTM to GA?

Tags: google-analytics, tags, google-tag-manager

I will start with describing what I am trying to achieve, in order to avoid x-y problem. And if the solution I try to apply is not the best one, please, tell me a different one.

I have a website. There is an audio player on it. I would like to track in my GA how many users started the audio, how many users listened 25% of it, how many users listened 50% of it and so on. I can access the needed information (e.g. user reached 25%, so it is time to tell about this to GA through GTM) in client-side JavaScript, the question is only about setting up the GTM and GA correctly.

So, now that I described my intentions, let me show what I was able to do so far.

**1** I created a custom metric with Hit scope in GA.
[image]

**2** I created a tag which increments the metric created in the **1**.
[image]
[image]

**3** I created a custom event in GTM. When user starts playing the audio I fire the event with the help of dataLayer. And the event fires the tag which I created in **2**.
[image]
[image]

**4** I created a custom dashboard in GA to track how many users started the sound.
[image]
[image]

And now I am stuck. I get the needed data from my website to GTM. I trigger the tag which should send the data over to GA. I have the needed metric and dashboard set up in GA. And now I would expect the widget in my custom dashboard in GA to show that the audio was started, but it does not happen.

I am very new to GA and GTM and may not understand some concepts, as a result I may miss some necessary for troubleshooting information. I will gladly provide it if you need it.

Thank you (y).

Comment: If you want to "bucket" users into 25%,50% etc. you need a custom dimension, not a metric. Metrics are added up, that's not what you want.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, I will create custom metrics for 25%, 50%, etc and then create the respective events to trigger the respective tags. But for this all to happen I need to understand why it does not work for `Users started to listen audio` metric first. And that is what the question is all about. Then I will just apply the same approach for registering how many users listened till 0, 25%, 50%, etc percents of the audio. Thank you.

Comment: You don't have to listen to me, but if you do not understand the difference between metrics and dimensions and when to use which, then you will not be able to make any sense from Google Analytics. You want different categories with users who have seen 25,50,75 etc percent of your page. If you want to categorize users you cannot do this with metrics.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, right now I want to keep track of how many users started to listen for an audio. Thank you.